# odbcException was unhandled

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp, config

ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.0.45-community-nt]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from petugas where nama='ANTON', and kode_petugas='ADM01'' at line 1

how to resolved it problem.

Comment: the syntax of your query is incorrect. please [edit] the question to add relevant details, like the query itself. voting to close for lack of context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used `,` or at the end of line `ADM01` not `ADM01`, thats the error.

use following query,

```
from petugas where nama='ANTON' and kode_petugas='ADM01'
```

Comment: if i change same code above will be error on the code this...ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.0.45-community-nt]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from petugas where nama=' & TextBox1.Text & ', and kode_petugas=' & MenuUtama.Pa' at line 1

Comment: from petugas where nama=' " & TextBox1.Text & ' ", and kode_petugas=' "& MenuUtama.Pa & " ' "